# What is the proper way to use an IDE to work on remote code?

Tags: web-development, linux, production

One of the code bases I work on has a development environment that is running on a dev server and cannot be copied over to my PC to locally test and develop. I am wondering what is the proper way to work with this code base? It is object oriented and I have found it to be very tedious and time consuming to do my work using Vim when working on such a codebase.

I have another project which I have running locally and I like to use Eclipse and sometimes Sublime text to make changes to the codebase.

Is there a way to utilize such tools that I use locally with a remote project, and if so what is the proper way to set this up?

Should I remotely mount my system? We do have git/hg setup with these environments however I like to test and debug things in very small changes and this would produce a lot of commits that are un-needed. As well it is also time consuming. Ideally it would be great to just be able to work like it is a local environment and when I save and refresh a page the change is there.

Is my best solution mounting?

Comment: On SO [Is it possible to work on remote files in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473154/is-it-possible-to-work-on-remote-files-in-eclipse) (questions of tools are often best asked on StackOverflow)

Comment: If you have any experience with emacs then you can use TRAMP (http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) to access the code remotely w/o much fuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our software is developed and executes on AIX, but the AIX boxes a locked down so running Eclipse in AIX is not posisble (let alone what happens when 10 poeple fire eclipse on one server).

I mount my source folder locally (NFS on a Linux box) and run Eclipse on the linux box. Builds are done by shelling across to the AIX server and runnig the build. The outbput is captured by eclipse.

In my case we use SCons. I used to have a Makefile that shelled and ran SCons, now I use sconsolidar and the SConstruct file detects its running on a linux box and the working folder is mounted, looks up the mount point and sheels to the AIX box.

Its not just Eclipse, any tool availble on Linux is not able to be used on my source files. Mounting is a very versilitle solution.